# C# code behaves differently in localhost vs live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh, publish, pageload

I have the following C# code in my code behind for a regular Web Application:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!validTime())
    {
        btnEdit.Enabled = false;
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false; btnSubmit2.Enabled = false;
        lblSuccess.Text = "It is not currently the time to edit picks for this week.";
        lblSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        if (picksMade())
        {
            displayCurrentPicks();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (picksMade())
        {
            btnEdit.Enabled = true;
            btnSubmit.Enabled = false; 
            btnSubmit2.Enabled = false;
            displayCurrentPicks();
            lblSuccess.Text = "Viewing your current picks";
            lblSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            if (Session["Success"] != null && Session["Success"].ToString() != String.Empty)
            {
                lblSuccess.Text = Session["Success"].ToString();
                lblSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                Session.Remove("Success");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnEdit.Enabled = false;
            btnSubmit.Enabled = true; btnSubmit2.Enabled = true;
            displayCreatePicks();
            lblSuccess.Text = "Create your picks for this week";
            lblSuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this code works great when I test it using ASP.NET Development Server. When I publish it to my live server it has some different behavior.

I have a web method that inserts data into my database with this signature:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void savePicks(List<string> Points, List<string> Teams, List<string> TieBreaker)
```

Again, on the test server it runs and works great. The problem is, when the method returns it should refresh the page, and it does, but on the live server my code in the page_load event is not run? or is run differently? It never calls the displayCurrentPicks() method? Or if it does, it does not run correctly? except it runs perfectly on the test server.

I have no way to check this stepping through the code because when I do it works great, on the test server. The live server is hosted on Godaddy.

And I have tried everything. I have tried doing page refreshes after the correct methods and in my javascript to force the page_load event to be run again. Nothing works. I have been at this for a few days now. And I am sure all my code is publishing. I have done all the usual 'stupid checks'. The data is making it to the database, the picksMade() function returns true when there is data there. The data is there by the time the page refreshes.

Why does the live server not run the code I publish to it? Why does it run something different? Or Behave differently? I understand it is a different server, but shouldn't it run the code the same?

Comment: Is the web method in the same page? It doesn't gets executed and no error?

Comment: How about inserting some logging functions to find out exactly what *does* and *doesn't* get called?

Comment: Are you using the built-in ASP.NET Development server or using IIS Express?  If it is the built-in one then I would recommend trying it with IIS Express as that might allow you to better debug what it is doing on live server.

Comment: The web method is on the same page. I know it gets executed because the data is put into the database. On the test server it shows no errors.

Comment: I am using the built in ASP.NET Development Server. I will look up using IIS Express and doing some logging functions. All good ideas.

Comment: You said "It never calls the displayCurrentPicks() method?" is it possible that `Page_Load()` is getting called but the logic isn't reaching `displayCurrentPicks()`?

Comment: I switched over to IIS Express Server and now the test server is behaving like the live server. This may help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the function validTime() do?  If you are checking for specific time constraints it may be that your development server is set to your local time zone and that is why it is working but on your live server the timezone may be different.  Just a guess though.

Comment: Valid time checks the date and time of today vs a constant stored in my database. I have tested that function and it appears to be working. All the dates are 3 months in the future, so it always returns true until that time. DateTime d = DateTime.MaxValue;
            if (!rdr.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                d = rdr.GetDateTime("final_update_time");
            }
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            mycon.Close();
            return (now < d);

Comment: I can remove the valid time check all together and still get the same behavior.

Comment: Are you expecting the displayCurrentPicks method that is in the else block to run on postback? If so, does the lblSuccess.Text value display the expected string, "Viewing your current picks"?